Neo4J Graph Cypher Query - Formula Relationship Traversal
This graph model represents BusinessRule nodes (formulas) and ChartField nodes (values).  A BusinessRule node will have "USES" relationships with ChartField nodes that are parameters for the BusinessRule formula.  The BusinessRule will have 1 "OUTPUTS" relationship to a ChartField node that is the target of the BusinessRule calculation.
I am attempting to return all ChartField and BusinessRule nodes that could either be impacted by a change in an in initial ChartField node value or would be required by a BusinessRule to perform the calculation.  With this in mind, we would always start with a ChartField node.
I have the following cypher query:
MATCH (start:ChartField {Id: '2025-BUDGET-11058201'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {
    relationshipFilter: "USES|OUTPUTS>",
    labelFilter: ">BusinessRule|>ChartField",
    uniqueness: "NODE_GLOBAL"
}) YIELD path
RETURN path;

There are two types of node types

ChartField
BusinessRule

The query will always start by matching on a ChartField node. In this case it is matching on the "Tours Taken" ChartField node.
The Problem
I need the cypher to return any BusinessRule node connected to the initial ChartField node that is matched, and I need any ChartFiefld node that is either an OUTPUT or a USES relationship to the BusinessRule nodes.
I also need to continue to traverse the relationships, so that if an ChartField node is related to the initial BusinessRule node via a "OUTPUTS" relationship, but also is related to a different BusinessRule node via a "USES" relationship, that we continue to work down that dependency and find the next level of BusinessRules and ChartField nodes.
This query mostly accomplsihes this. But what I want to avoid: I don't need additional BusinessRule nodes or its connected ChartField nodes unless the relationship is "OUTPUTS".
You can see from the graph below where I have crossed out in red. Those nodes shouldn't be returned.  While the "Contract %" node is necessary because I need it for the calculation, because that relationship to its BusinessRule node isn't "OUTPUTS", I don't need to find any other BusinessRule nodes that the "Contract %" ChartField node may be tied to.
I know this is a bit winded. But I want to start with that "Tours Taken" ChartField node, and return everything that is seen in the image below, except what i have crossed out.


Although your apoc example returns the paths, you state that you just want the nodes, so I will go with that in the following.
To match your rules, it is easiest to gather the BusinessRule nodes with a quantified path pattern in one MATCH clause, and then gather the ChartField nodes linked to those BusinessRules nodes in a second MATCH:
MATCH (start:ChartField {Id: '2025-BUDGET-11058201'})<-[:USES]-(:BusinessRule)
      ( ()-[:OUTPUTS]->(:ChartField)<-[:USES]-(:BusinessRule) )* 
      (br)
WITH DISTINCT br
WITH [br] + 
    COLLECT {
        WITH br
        MATCH (br)-[:OUTPUTS|USES]-(cf:ChartField)
        RETURN cf 
    } AS nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
RETURN DISTINCT node

The COLLECT is there to enable the UNWIND and RETURN DISTINCT to return each node once and in a separate row.

This is fantastic.  Curious, in addition to the node return, can we also return the relationship information for reach node. So for example, lets say RETURN DISTINCT node brings back 13 nodes.  I'd like to see next to each of those 13 the specific relationships that the node has.  This should allow me to wire up this result into objects in C# that can be used to perform the actual calculations.

Glad that helped! For your second idea, do you mean a column with the nodes and a column with a list of the relationships linked to the node in that row?
